# Is it possible to build and run a cpp nodelet without Catkin or rosbuild?

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is similar to [link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/220219/how-to-use-ros-without-catkin-or-rosbuild/) but with using Nodelets instead of nodes.  Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393780/is-it-possible-to-build-and-run-a-cpp-nodelet-without-catkin-or-rosbuild??/) by [johnt](https://answers.ros.org/users/92852/johnt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is possible, although I wouldn't recommend it due to the difficulty of reproducing all the functionality offered by Catkin. rosbuild is easier to do without; you can just call CMake manually on your `CMakeLists.txt` file.

The main difference of building a nodelet from building a node is that you need to build a shared library rather than an executable.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2022-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [johnt](https://answers.ros.org/users/92852/johnt/) on 2022-01-05**:
Thanks, Geoff.  I appreciate your time.  Quick followup: Is there a way to give ROS visibility to the nodelet's shared object without the package infrastructure or do I need to create a package?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-01-06**:
Other nodes will be using `pluginlib` to discover and load the nodelet (ie: shared library), and `pluginlib` uses `rospkg`. The latter will only consider directories with a manifest in them as "ROS packages", so at the very minimum you'd have to place a `package.xml` with the correct contents in a directory. That manifest could then point to wherever the shared library is which hosts the nodelet class.

As "a directory with a manifest" is basically the definition of a package (at least at the file system level), theoretically this could work, but you'd essentially still be creating a package.

---

Edit: that's assuming the consumers of your nodelet-not-built-using-Catkin are in fact regular ROS nodes.

---

Edit 2: perhaps also good to mention: Catkin the CMake macros/functions/syntactic sugar != `catkin_make` (ie: the tool). Those are often confused/conflated.